# How to use ARN to connect to DynamoDb with spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, spring-cloud

I'm integrating our app with a remote DynamoDb. The app is using spring boot and the only available information I have on the db is it's ARN. I'm still very green in AWS, mostly hands-on experience only, so I'm not even sure it's possible to use the ARN, but it is possible how's it done?

Currently we're using the newly released [spring-cloud-aws-starter-dynamodb](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws), saying support is sparse at the moment is an understatement. We're on Kotlin 1.7.22 and Java17.

Answer (score 2):

To develop a Spring BOOT app that uses Amazon DynamoDB, look at using **[AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)**. This is the official SDK from AWS - not the 3rd party https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws.

A benefit of using the Offical SDK is it's supported.

To learn how to use **Amazon DynamoDB** from a Spring Boot app, refer to the link below. This discusses how to develop a Spring Boot application that queries Amazon DynamoDB data. The Spring Boot application uses the ***AWS SDK for Java (v2)*** to invoke AWS services and is used by a React application that displays the data.

[Create a web application to track DynamoDB data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_cross_DynamoDBDataTracker_section.html)

This example shows use of the [DynamoDB Enhanced Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html) to map Java classes to the DynamoDB table. Therefore to use this client, you need to know details about the table. Using only the ARN of the table is not enough information.

You can find full code in the link above.

ALso note - if you want to implement your solution in Kotlin, this example has a Kotlin example that uses the [AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/home.html).

Comment: Hey @smac2020 thanks for the links, I'll take a look. I actually do know the schema of the table, but we are only allowed to use ARN to connect.

Comment: If you work through that doc - you will gain a better understanding of AWS DynamoDB Java API and how to apply that to your projects.

Comment: Are you aware of how to use the ARN with Spring for Dynamo? I can't see it in any of the example in the AWS pages

Comment: The Request objects for AWS DynamoDB service client methods accept the table name - not the ARN. For example, see the request object on this method. https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#describeTable(software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DescribeTableRequest)